# Prove that $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$ where $A_n = \{m \in \mathbb{Z}: \exists q \ni m = n + 5q\}$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

This is the first exercise of section 3.3 from *A Book of Set Theor*y by Charles C. Pinter.

This is my attempt to solve it, please tell me where I'm doing wrong:

To prove that $A_n$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Z}$, we must prove that:

P1: $$If\:\exists x \in A_i \cap A_j, then \: A_i=A_j$$
P2: $$If \:x \in A,  then\: x \in A_i \:for\: some\: i \in I$$

Suppose $A_i \cap A_j$ is a non-empty set. We must prove that $A_i = A_j$

Let $y \in A_i$. Then by definition of $A_n$, there exists some $k$ such that $y = i + 5k$. We should prove that $y \in A_j$. Add and substract 5 from the right hand side:
$$y = i + 5k + 5 -5$$
$$y = i + 5 + 5(k - 1)$$

Now let $j = i + 1$. Then $y \in A_j$ for $j = i + 5$ and $q = k + 1$.

**Proof of P2**:
Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. We must prove that $n \in A_i$ for some $i \in I$. But this can be easily shown to be true by the quotient-reminder theorem.

Comment: If you already know about partitions induced by the classes of an equivalence relation then show that congruence is an equivalence relation and  $A_n$ is the class of integers $\,m\equiv n\pmod{\!5}\ $